# How to load gdbinit while debugging?

Tags: ubuntu, debugging, gdb, gdbinit

When I start to debug with gdb I edit few breakpoints and commands into gdbinit file.

How can I change this file and load it again while I debugging without detach from process?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I change this file and load it again

There is nothing special about this file (other than it's automatically read by GDB at startup) -- it's just a file of GDB commands.

You can reread it with `(gdb) source ~/.gdbinit`.

Comment: But this only add the breakpoints and commands that into new source file. It doesn't delete all the breakpoints and commands that were into old file

Comment: @Kokomelom You didn't _ask_ to dele all the old breakpoints. There is "reset everything to defaults" command (AFAICT), you have to do it manually. E.g. `delete breakpoints` will delete all current breakpoints.

Comment: @Kokomelom You can of course put `delete breakpoints` as the first line of `~/.gdbinit`, so every time it's (re)loaded you start afresh.